# How can I repair a tar file where stderr got mixed with stdout?

Tags: text-processing, grep, tar

I have a tar file that I'm trying to repair. The problem is that `tar`'s stderr got mixed in with its `stdout`, so the file looks like this:

```
% head android-1435613730.tar
tar: removing leading '/' from member names
factory/0000775000175100017510000000000007033241671011512 5ustar  radioradiofactory/
factory/lost+found/0000700000000000000000000000000000000000000013242 5ustar  rootrootfactory/lost+found/
tar: /factory/lost+found: Permission denied
factory/wifi/0000770000175000017510000000000007033241625012667 5ustar  systemradiofactory/wifi/
tar: /factory/wifi: Permission denied
factory/imei/0000775000175100017510000000000007033241600012425 5ustar  radioradiofactory/imei/
tar: can't open '/factory/nv_data.bin': Permission denied
tar: can't open '/factory/nv_data.bin.md5': Permission denied
factory/bluetooth/0000755000175100017510000000000007033241674013520 5ustar  radioradiofactory/bluetooth/
```

I've tried stripping the error messages, like so:

```
% grep --color=never -v --binary-file=text '^tar:.*$' android-1435613730.tar | tar -tv
drwxrwxr-x radio/radio       0 1999-12-31 16:00 factory/
tar: Skipping to next header
drwx------ install/all_a124  0 2015-06-29 13:51 acct/uid/50124/
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

But as you can see, this yields an error. (I'll spare you the awful binary data file dump, unless it's *really* needed.)

I should also point out that this file is quite large (6.7 GB), and I don't have that much core or swap available.

The tarball is being untar'd with the same `tar` that was used to create it, GNU Tar 1.27.1.

On the suggestion of @kos, I tried using Perl:

```
% <android-1435613730.tar perl -pe 's/\n?tar: [^\n]*\n//sg' | tar -tv
drwxrwxr-x radio/radio       0 1999-12-31 16:00 factory/
tar: Skipping to next header
drwx------ install/all_a83   0 2015-06-29 13:55 acct/uid/50083/
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

For your convenience, here's a script to recreate the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
cd $TMPDIR
for i in test test2 test3; do
    mkdir $i
    echo $i > $i/$i
done
chmod 000 test2/test2
chmod 000 test3
tar -c test* > broken.tar 2>&1

echo "Created corrupt tarball in $TMPDIR"
```

Although in my tarball the errors are mixed into the middle, which I couldn't seem to reproduce here.

Comment: This will be hard, but those 00000.... fields will have NUL delimiters - well, they will if the contents of the field does not fill the whole field, and it usually doesn't. So there are twelve fields in that header, probably NUL delimmed, and the file size is one of those fields. So the header will be 512bytes, and the file is everything that follows minus `$((size&511))` until the next header and there's your stderr junk. You might get lucky and just prune stuff that looks like *`/factory...Permission`* if the file contents can't match it, but you can always check against the size.

Comment: Can you post the output of `tail android-1435613730.tar`, or some lines taken from the middle of the file? I suspect the line-buffering of `tar`'s `stdout` being limited to the headers: if that's the case (e.g. no buffering after the headers) there might be some `tar: [...]` lines from `stderr` "breaking" the stream of `stdout`, for which you'd need to remove the leading newline also.

Answer (score 3):

As long as `stdout` and `stderr` are line-buffered and the lines of one of the two are always spottable, mixing them is not a problem: consider the output of a program where both `stdout` and `stderr` are line-buffered, and where `stderr` is easily spottable:

```
$ cat file
xxxxxxxxxx
tar: ----------
yyyyyyyyyy
tar: ----------
zzzzzzzzzz
tar: ----------
```

Extracting either of the two using `grep` is not a problem:

```
$ < file grep -v ^tar
xxxxxxxxxx # stdout line 1
yyyyyyyyyy # stdout line 2
zzzzzzzzzz # stdout line 3
$ < file grep ^tar
tar: ---------- # stderr line 1
tar: ---------- # stderr line 2
tar: ---------- # stderr line 3
```

However, consider the case in which at some point `stdout`'s buffering behavior changes to, say, unbuffered:

```
x
tar: ----------
xxxxxxxxxyyy
tar: ----------
yyyyyyyzzzzz
tar: ----------
zzzzz
```

Extracting `stdout` using `grep` **is** a problem:

```
$ < file grep -v ^tar
x # wrong stdout line 1
xxxxxxxxxyyy # wrong stdout line 2
yyyyyyyzzzzz # wrong stdout line 3
zzzzz # wrong stdout line 4
```

Try this instead:

```
< file perl -0777pe 's/\n?tar: [^\n]*\n//g' > newfile
```

Which, excluding [edge] cases should extract the original `stdout` from the file:

```
$ < file perl -0777pe 's/\n?tar: [^\n]*\n//g'
xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzz
```

Comment: That's nice, but stdout is probably not line-buffered in this situation.

Comment: @Gilles Judging from OP's `head` output, `stdout` is line-buffered during the output of the headers; at least in GNU `tar`, the data section is instead buffered to a multiple of 512 bytes (I can't tell whether such chunks are newline-separated or not), so there *might* be sections of continuous output from `stdout` in the data section broken by `stderr`; `grep`ping every line but `stderr` lines like OP did seemed reasonable, however if the output chunks happened to be *not* newline-separated, that most likely left an excessive leading newline per each `stderr` flush.

Comment: @kos: when executing your answer I get "out of memory".

Comment: @strugee That's because Perl is slurping the whole file and because your archive is probably big. I can't test now however try this: `< file perl -pe 's/\n?tar: [^\n]*\n//sg' > newfile`

Comment: @kos yeah, that's what I assumed, so I searched in `perl(1)` for "buffer" but didn't find anything. I'll try that.

Comment: @kos question updated.

Comment: @strugee That command is wrong thinking about it twice. Try this, make a backup of the archive and edit it in-place: `perl -0777pe -i 's/\n?tar: [^\n]*\n//g' backup`

Comment: perl's `-i` flag isn't really _in place_; it's a [shorthand](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for "move the current file elsewhere, open it, and write the output to the original name". So copying the file and using plain `-i` doesn't really save you anything over `-i.bak`. I like the direction of your solution. This could be stunningly useful.

Comment: @roaima That's true. I didn't know about that. Well this invalidates my other solution then, because at this point most likely Perl will try to load the whole file even using `-i`.

Comment: @kos `Can't open s/\n?tar: [^\n]*\n//g: No such file or directory.` after that there's the "out of memory" error again. maybe there's some way to split the file in the middle of the actual tar data?

Comment: @strugee I'm sorry, my bad again, the `-i` option must be before: `perl -i -0777pe 's/\n?tar: [^\n]*\n//g' backup`. Hopefully this will buffer the loading of the file into the memory, however yes, I was thinking right about that, but it shall be done wisely, in order to not split the file in the middle of a `stderr` line. Try this for now, in the meantime I'll try to work out a solution using `split`

Comment: @strugee Ok this should work: `split -C 1000000 file` (or less, in this case each part could be up to 1GB), then running the command on each part and then joining them back using `cat file* > newfile`. However there's a weakness in the Perl command, i.e. it won't strip a possible `tar: [...]` line at the end of each part (like it wouldn't have even if run on the whole file). Run `grep tar` on each part after having processed it using the Perl command to make sure that each part is really clean. In case you can strip it with `head -n $(($(< partname wc -l)-1)) partname > newpartname`

Comment: @kos somehow that split doesn't work. I'll add the log to my question. thanks for your help, by the way.